# How to add data into array of redux store, which will be created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on nested todo app, I have todos array in my store. When I dispatch an action, {task:todo, id:id, singletodo:[]} will be created. I have done routing according to id, whenever I click on any todo, it will take me to that particular todo. I have created another reducer which will add new sub-todo for main todo to the singletodo array. I have tried various ways but nothing seems to work. I am attaching code in snippet.

Reducers:

```js
 ADD_TODO: (state, action) => {
      state.todos.push(action.payload);
    },
    ADD_Single_TODO: (state, action) => {
      state.todos.singletodo.push(action.payload);
    },
```

Dispatch action for addition of todo:

```js
  function handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(ADD_TODO({ task: tasks, id: cuid(),singletodo: [] }));
  }
```

Dispatch action for adding sub-todo:

```js
  let single = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    //todo array from store
    let alldata = useSelector(selectdata);
    //id for main todo
    const id = props.match.params.id;
    alldata.map((todo) => {
      if(todo.id === id) {
        dispatch(ADD_Single_TODO({ task: tasks, id: cuid() }));
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve], using something like codesandbox

Comment: `todos array in my store` so why you have `todos.singletodo`?

Comment: How can I push data into singletodo array? Each object of todos array contains singletodo array, and I am trying to push sub-todos in singletodo array for respective object or for respective todo

Comment: 1. Don't mutate the state i.e. don't use `push` (`state.todos.push`) 2. Don't use `.map`. Use `forEach` for looping (try `.find` when you are trying to find a matching item).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I made the changes the in reducer and also in dispatch action.

Updated reducer:

```js
ADD_TODO: (state, action) => {
      state.todos.push(action.payload);
    },
    ADD_Single_TODO: (state, action) => {
        state.todos.map((todo)=>{
          if(todo.id === action.payload.id ){
            todo.singletodo.push(action.payload)
          }
        })

    },
```

Updated dispatched action:

```js
 let single = ()=>{
    dispatch(ADD_Single_TODO({ task: tasks, id: props.match.params.id, newid:cuid() }))
    setTasks('')
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In legacy Redux like you are writing here, you are not allowed to use `.push` and other mutating functions (see https://doesitmutate.xyz/ ) on data managed by redux.
That is one of the three core principles of redux (see https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/three-principles#state-is-read-only ) and would cause for a lot of bugs with react not rerendering corerctly etc.

You will have to write much more complicated immutable update logic or - which I would recommend - follow the official redux tutorials ( at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts ) and learn modern redux, which abstracts that "immutability" part for you and allows you to also use mutating logic.